# Accessing cached objects from view template in Play! 2.1 framework

Tags: java, scala, caching, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm storing logged in User object in Play cache (`using play.cache.Cache`) like this.

```
User user = userRepo.findUserFromDB(id);
String uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
Cache.set(uuid, user);
session("uuid", uuid);
```

I want to use this object in every view I render (to display information about logged in user in the footer template). One way would be to pass this object to views from every controller as an argument, but it's definitely not the way of doing it.

```
String uuid = session("uuid") 
User user = Cache.get(uuid);
return ok(
        dashboard.render(user, other_params)
    );
```

What would be the most elegant way of doing it to maximize code re-use?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I access the cache in the view template by calling

```
@play.api.cache.Cache.get(key)
```

But my cache is nothing but a String of JSON data so I'm not sure if it will work for you in your case of objects. Maybe try something like:

```
@play.api.cache.Cache.get(key).name
```

where `name` is the object's attribute and see if that works?

Also remember to `@import play.api.Play.current` at the top of the template if you're trying to access the cache in the view template.

Comment: You can't access the object properties, so, @play.api.cache.Cache.get(key).name doesn't work. you get "value 'name' is not a member of object" and it is a compile time error. I wish there is some way to achieve this.